# How to Stream VOD on Django with Nginx-rtmp

Tags: django, nginx, video-streaming, rtmp

I have a problem when I try to stream VOD on Django.
I have been follow this link for streaming VOD with nginx-rtmp-module and I succeeded:
https://helping-squad.com/setup-a-simple-video-on-demand-server-with-nginx-rtmp/

So after that, I install Django follow this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

and my problem is JWplayer has notified me "Error loading stream: Could not connect to server"
Im fresher so I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by edit file nginx.conf in /usr/local/nginx same as myproject file in /etc/nginx/sites-avaiable.
After that, I turn off nginx by systemctl stop nginx and just start nginx with usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx. It's worked.